# Geocoder throwing odd exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, geocoding

I have a method that is triggered on the press of a button. This is most of the implmentation:

```
[self.placeDictionary setValue:@"166 Bovet Rd" forKey:@"Street"];
    [self.placeDictionary setValue:@"San Mateo"  forKey:@"City"];
    [self.placeDictionary setValue:@"CA" forKey:@"State"];
    [self.placeDictionary setValue:@"94402" forKey:@"ZIP"];

    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressDictionary:self.placeDictionary completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if([placemarks count]) {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
            PFGeoPoint* userLocation = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude longitude:coordinate.longitude];
            NSLog(@"%f,%f", userLocation.latitude, userLocation.longitude); 
        } else {
            NSLog(@"location error");
            return;
        }
    }];
```

However, I am getting the following exception:

```
*** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:shouldInsertText:replacingDOMRange:givenAction: delegate: <NSUnknownKeyException> [<__NSDictionaryI 0x873a3c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Street.
```

I have absolutely no idea what this exception means. Could someone help me understand why it is producing this?

Comment: Try to change your declaration of placeDictionary property from NSDictionary to NSMutableDictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you are trying to add objects to an immutable dictionary. The part of the exception beginning `[<__NSDictionaryI 0x873a3c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:` gives a class name of `__NSDictionaryI`, which is an immutable member of the `NSDictionary` class cluster - so you cannot add any objects to it at run-time. You need to ensure that `self.placeDictionary` is assigned to an `NSMutableDictionary` instance before this code is called.

Unfortunately, you are also using the wrong method to add the objects - you're using `setValue:forKey:` instead of `setObject:forKey:`. Since this method is part of the `NSKeyValueCoding` informal protocol, you're not stopped from doing this at compile time. You should instead use `setObject:forKey:` which is the correct method to set key-value pairs on an `NSMutableDictionary`. After you correct the first issue, replace the `setValue:forKey:` calls with `setObject:forKey:`, for example:

```
[self.placeDictionary setObject:@"San Mateo"  forKey:@"City"];
```